# Use IP adress from ini file in playbook or template

Tags: ansible

we are using Ansible to configure ElasticSearch cluster. I would like to use values from my inventory.ini file. I have something like below:

```
[server: children]
server1
server2
server3 ip=xxxx
server4 ip=xxxx
```

I would need to them use in playbook. But it must be in this string. So in playbook it would looks like

```
"server1", "server2" or "xxxxx", "xxxxx"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below formatting:

```
[server: children]
server1 ansible_host=<server1_ip>
```